# How to find pairs of integers in a list that add up to a target in O(N)?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an input list

```
lst = [2, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

If I say `target = 7`, I would like to get

```
[(0, 4), (1, 2)]
```

These are the indices of the pairs of numbers in `lst` which add up to `target` (7).

How we can obtain the expected result using a single `for` loop?

Comment: You can use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations): `[(i1, i2) for ((i1, v1), (i2, v2)) in combinations(enumerate(Input), 2) if v1 + v2 == Target]`. If you want to reimplement it, take a look on docs, there's an implementation.

Comment: @OlvinRoght that's still O(N**2)

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: for every number `n` at index `i` you encounter, you need to find an index `j` that contains `7 - n`. You can do this in a single pass over the list by maintaining the following structures:

- A list of the pairs you've found so far
- A map of `7 - n`: `i`, so that when you encounter `7 - n` at index `j`, you can add the pair `i, j`

A simple approach using just one loop would be

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_target(data, target):
    pairs = []
    found = defaultdict(list)
    for i, n in enumerate(data):
        m = target - n
        found[m].append(i)
        if n in found:
            pairs.extend((j, i) for j in found[n])
    return pairs
```

Using `defaultdict` to hold a list of indices for all the possible duplicates is a simple way to ensure that you get all the possible combinations.

For your specific case:

```
>>> find_target([2, 4, 3, 6, 5], 7)
[(1, 2), (0, 4)]
```

The result is sorted by the second index (since that determines when a pair enters the list). If you want to sort it by the first index, you can do so:

```
>>> result = find_target([2, 4, 3, 6, 5], 7)
>>> result.sort()
>>> result
[(0, 4), (1, 2)]
```

Or more wastefully,

```
>>> sorted(find_target([2, 4, 3, 6, 5], 7))
[(0, 4), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: @notarobot. It's a matter of interpretation, and I can see yours being just as valid as mine. In that case, put `found[m].append(i)` after the `if` statement that currently follows it

Answer (score -1):

In a *single* list-comprehension: filter by target-value and skip duplicate values.

```
target = 7
lst = [2, 4, 3, 6, 5]

output = [(i1, i2) for i1, j1 in enumerate(lst) for i2, j2 in enumerate(lst) if j1+j2 == target and i1 < i2]
print(output)
```

or, to avoid the `and`, using a slice (together with a shift of the `i2`-index):

```
[(i1, i2) for i1, j1 in enumerate(lst) for i2, j2 in enumerate(lst[i1:], start=i1) if j1+j2 == target]
```

---

As a *single* for loop. Idea: iterate over the size of the "set" of **all** pairs (not used filter-by-distance as in the answer of Mad Physicist):

```
lst = [2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]
target = 7

out = []
n = len(lst)
blk = n-1
loop_counter = 1
c = 0
for i in range(n*(n-1)//2):
    # indices
    a, b = n-blk-1, c % blk + n-blk

    # check condition
    if lst[a] + lst[b] == target:
        out.append((a, b))

    # next iteration
    c+=1
    if c % blk == 0:
        blk -= 1
        c = 0
        loop_counter += 1

print(out)
#[(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)]
```

Comment: Or use indexes which should be most efficient implementation of your method.

Comment: `[(i1, i2) for i1, v in enumerate(Input) for i2 in range(i1 + 1, len(Input)) if v + Input[i2] == Target]`

Comment: This is not a single loop and an a time inefficient approach to solving this problem

Comment: @Mad Physicist Hi! I am not good (at all!) in complexity... but you could you explain me the difference between my approach and yours? In mine: I used a longer list, of size `n(n-1)/2`, in yours: list of size `n` but with extra comprehension. How does affect the complexity?

Comment: Both of your approaches are O(n^2). `n*(n-1)/2` is `0.5 * (n^2 - n)`, which means that the number of iterations you do scales quadratically with additional elements. My solution passes over the data exactly once, so it scales linearly with the number of elements.

Comment: **Remark:** the original question did not include any optimization constraints such as to be O(N)